# The request is too large for IE to process properly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, websync

I am using `Websync3`, Javascript API, and subscribing to approximately 9 different channels on one page. Firefox and Chrome have no problems, but IE9 is throwing an alert error stating `The request is too large for IE to process properly`.
Unfortunately the internet has little to no information on this. So does anyone have any clues as to how to remedy this?

```
    var client = fm.websync.client;

    client.initialize({ 
        key: '********-****-****-****-************'
    });

    client.connect({
        autoDisconnect: true,
        onStreamFailure: function(args){
            alert("Stream failure");
        },
        stayConnected: true
    });

    client.subscribe({
        channel: '/channel',
        onSuccess: function(args) {
            alert("Successfully connected to stream");
        },

        onFailure: function(args){
            alert("Failed to connect to stream");
        },

        onSubscribersChange: function(args) {
            var change = args.change;
            for (var i = 0; i < change.clients.length; i++) {
                var changeClient = change.clients[i];

                // If someone subscribes to the channel
                if(change.type == 'subscribe') {

                // If something unsubscribes to the channel
                }else{

                }
            }
        },

        onReceive: function(args){
            text = args.data.text;
            text = text.split("=");
            text = text[1];
            if(text != "status" && text != "dummytext"){
                //receiveUpdates(id, serial_number, args.data.text);
            var update = eval('(' + args.data.text + ')');

    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when WebSync is using the JSON-P protocol for transfers. This is mostly just for IE, cross domain environments. Meaning websync is on a different domain than your webpage is being served from. So IE doesn't want do make regular XHR requests for security reasons.

JSON-P basically encodes the up-stream data (your 9 channel subscriptions) as a URL encoded string that is tacked onto a regular request to the server. The server is supposed to interpret that URL-encoded string and send back the response as a JavaScript block that gets executed by the page.

This works fine, except that IE also has a limit on the overall request URL for an HTTP request of roughly 2kb. So if you pack too much into a single request to WebSync you might exceed this 2kb upstream limit.

The easiest solution is to either split up your WebSync requests into small pieces (ie: subscribe to only a few channels at a time in JavaScript), or to subscribe to one "master channel" and then program a WebSync BeforeSubscribe event that watches for that channel and re-writes the subscription channel list.

I suspect because you have a key in you example source above, you are using WebSync On-Demand? If that's the case, the only way to make a BeforeSubscribe event handler is to create a WebSync proxy.

Comment: As of WebSync 4, JSON-P is only used in IE7 and below. Newer techniques (postMessage, CORS, WebSockets, etc.) can be used in IE8+.

Answer (score 1):

So for the moment, since everyone else is stumped by this question as well, I put a trap in my `PHP` to not even load this `Javascript` script if the browser is `Internet Destroyer` (uhh, I mean `Internet Explorer`). Maybe a solution will come in the future though.